# a dynamic membership error in Azure groups

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, rbac, abac, azure-rbac

I am new in Azure AD and trying to learn dynamic membership group for ABAC. However, when i click on groups, it shows below error, so i cant create a dynamic membership group. Any solution please? Thanks in advance.
[image: Azure Groups error - Dynamic group memberships have not been updated due to system delays. We’re working to resolve the issue.]

Answer (score 0):

> Note that, the error usually occurs if the **signed-in user** account
> does not have **"Enterprise Mobility + Security E5"** license assigned.

I have one user account named **`Sri`** without any license like this:

[image]

When I visited `All groups` tab by signing in with above user account, I too got **same error** :

[image]

To resolve the issue, I assigned **Enterprise Mobility + Security E5** license to the user account like this:

[image]

When I refreshed the page after assigning license, error disappeared and I'm able to create **dynamic group** successfully like below:

[image]

**Reference:**
[Dynamic group memberships have not been updated - Microsoft Q&A by **Tyler Vining**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1078515/dynamic-group-memberships-have-not-been-updated-du)